# Why doesn't my created DB show up when I doe show databases in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I tried going into a mongo shell and creating a DB, and it seems to have worked, its saying I'm in the db i created but when I run show databases; it doesnt show in the list.
Here is what terminal shows:

```
> show databases;
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> use sr-dev
switched to db sr-dev
> show databases;
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> db
sr-dev
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo only creates databases and collections *as needed*, as lazily as possible. You didn't *"create"* `sr-dev`, you're merely "using" it at the moment. Think of it as "being in the namespace `sr-dev`". Once you insert your first data the actual database will be created. Before you do that, there's no need for it to exist.

> #### Create a Database
>
> If a database does not exist, MongoDB creates the database when you first store data for that database. As such, you can switch to a non-existent database and perform the following operation in the mongo shell: [..]
>
> <sub>https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/#create-a-database</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you create a database in MongoDb shell, it won't show up until there are some collections in your database.

Please try adding some collections in your newly created database and run show databases command again, It will show up.

`db.createCollection('collection_name',{...})`

Here the 2nd parameter is optional.

Please read [MongoDb createCollection documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) for more info, on 2nd parameter options.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create collection inside your db.
MongoDB works this way.